# Происхождение слова "салага"

Tags: этимология

Изначально, насколько я знаю, салагой называли только начинающего моряка, сейчас же это слово употребляется по адресу всех молодых военных.
А откуда оно вообще взялось и что изначально значило?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Салага (салака) - это рыба такая. ))))
Почему именно она стала синонимом необученного бойца (изначально, имхо, - матроса), сказать наверняка трудно. Вроде бы считалась рыбой глупой, но какая рыба умная? 
Скорее всего просто потому, что по причине дешевизны и легкости лова частенько попадала в матросское "меню".

Вот тут несколько "продвинутая" версия, но недостоверно, ибо фантастично.
http://otvet.mail.ru/question/14247653

Comment: Недостоверная  конечно - новодел.  Скорее  от  рыбы,  но  не  потому,  что  глупая,  а  просто  дешёвая,  обыденная.

Answer (score 3):

Вызывает  сомнения  очень  большая  древность  этого  выражения.  В  дореволюционных  словарях - ни  у  Даля,  ни  у  Преображенского,  ни  у  Михельсона - этого  слова  нет.  А  должны  были  бы  быть  у  Даля,  в  поморских  говорах,  например.  Все  словари  я,  конечно,  не  прошерстил,  но  "салагу"  в  нашем  значении  нашёл  только  в  Полутолковом  словаре  одесского  языка,  да  в  Словаре  морского  жаргона ( совр )  под  ред.  Каланова  Н.А.  В  этом  словаре  упоминается  и  слово  "салака". Так  что  "рыбное"  происхождение  мне  представляется  более  верным.  Так  же  я  думаю,  что  среда  бытования  этого  выражения  советский  ВМФ, ещё  довоенный.  Даже  для  80-х  это  давние  времена.[image]  Это  из  Словаря  морского  жаргона.  А  вот  комментарий  к  рассказу  из  80-х.[image]

Answer (score 1):

В. В. Хлебников. «На нем был котелок вселенной...» (1922) 
…Салага, по-морскому, веселый мальчуган…

Вероятно,  «донорами» нового слова стали: навага, белуга, юнга и, мелкая рыбка, обитающая в прибрежных водах, - салака.
У Брокгауза и Ефрона есть статья «салакушка (салака)», слово «салага» не удостоено вниманием. Видимо, слово еще не рождено (Хлебниковым?), или бытует в узком кругу.

Answer (score 0):

Мне почему-то думается , что та "продвинутая версия" , связанная с островом Алаг , на которую дана ссылка у BEHEMOTHUSа , более реальна , чем рыбка *салака* . Хотя можно выдвинуть и другую версию : немецкий -  **Schlag** [*шлаг*] , идиш - **שלאָגן** [*шлаг , слаг*] , - а перевод одинаков - БИТЬ . Во *время оно* дисциплина в армии и на флоте поддерживалась , главным образом , путём рукоприкладства , палки . И понятно , что к новобранцам (солдатам и матросам) такое обращение было самым обыденным действием . К тому же , со времен Петра I-го , в российской армии и флоте в офицерском составе служило много немцев и ашкеназов .

Comment: А  с  какого  времени  в  литературе  на  армейскую  или  флотскую  тематику  отмечается  это  слово ?

Comment: Вопрос вполне закономерный ! И ответ на него мог бы существенно прояснить какая версия тут наиболее приемлема ,особенно , если ещё и определить ,где именно это слово первоначально проявилось - на Балтике или , скажем , на Черном море , в котором салака не водится , и острова с названием Алаг тоже нету . Зато ашкеназы гуртами заселяли и Одессу , и Севастополь и другие порты .

Answer (score 0):

Есть любопытная версия, но за достоверность не ручаюсь. Алага, или олага, - очаг на корабле, печка, где готовилась еда для команды; слово вышло из употребления много веков назад. За очагом присматривал, как правило, младший член команды - мальчишка, подросток. Сейчас сказали бы "юнга", но в древности это слово не было известно; поморы говорили "зуёк" (по названию маленькой птички). Когда подросток начинал хвастаться - "Я - моряк, я в море ходил!", - над ним смеялись: "Моряк с алагой", подразумевая, что ничего, кроме как присматривать за очагом, ему на судне ещё не доверяют.

Answer (score -1):

А у меня еще мысль, молодых пацанов всегда на салинг за кипятком посылали.Если попал и до салинга дорогу спросил --салага. Так это еще на парусных кораблях было.